# Embed Growl in a Cocoa app iconData

Tags: cocoa, growl

I successfully implement Growl in my app. I still have a little problem.

It's possible to set the size of the icon (iconData in the code) in the notification? It's too small..

My code is:

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[AppController class]]; 
    NSString *growlPath = [[myBundle privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Growl.framework"];
    NSBundle *growlBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:growlPath];
    if (growlBundle && [growlBundle load]) {
        [GrowlApplicationBridge setGrowlDelegate:self];
        [GrowlApplicationBridge notifyWithTitle:@"ALERT!!!" description:@"\n\nNonloso" notificationName:@"Hack" iconData:[[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/blabla/image.JPG"] TIFFRepresentation] priority:2 isSticky:NO clickContext:[NSDate date]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image itself is not too small (I don't assume that), it is up to the active Growl theme to decide how large the image will be inside the notification. There's no way to change that from your code: it's up to the user to decide which Growl theme he wants to use.